# Delphi - Screenshot Quality

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I use this code to make a screenshot:

```
function GetScreenShot: TBitmap;
var
  Desktop: HDC;
begin
  Result  := TBitmap.Create;
  Desktop := GetDC(0);
  try
    try
      Result.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
      Result.Width := Screen.Width;
      Result.Height := Screen.Height;
      BitBlt(Result.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, Result.Width, Result.Height, 
        Desktop, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
      Result.Modified := True;
    finally
      ReleaseDC(0, Desktop);
    end;
  except
    Result.Free;
    Result := nil;
  end;
end;


procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Image1.Picture.Bitmap := GetScreenShot;
end;
```

Now I want to ask how I can change the Quality. For example I can choose between 25%, 50%, 75% and 100%.

How could I implement this into my code?

Comment: You have a memory leak in your code. TBitmap from your function will never be freed

Comment: The leak is in `Button1Click` rather than `GetScreenShot`, FWIW.

Comment: I've always done this by means of JPEG compression. 1) Snap a shot of the screen as BMP, 2) Assign the BMP to a JPG object, 3) Compress the JPG object.

Answer (score 5):

You can't specify size or quality of screenshot taken, but you can change one yourself later, for example check out this code: http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=7481

Comment: In addition to linked example: it may be useful to set SetStretchBltMode with HALFTONE

Comment: This answer becomes meaningless if the external website you linked is available for some reason; that's why we don't generally accept them here. Answers should contain enough content to stand on their own, with any links added as additional references. The exception to that is when you're linking to one of the major sites (like Microsoft, for instance), and there should still be a full explanation of what the link references.

Comment: @DannyRancher the example is not about the link, but about idea that you have to resize it on your own.

Comment: @DannyRancher once the link turns dead, you can google delphi resize image and pick any.